# How to use the Refresh() and Save() methods to add a callback to the form's save

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, xrmservicetoolkit

I want to add a callback to the form's save to fire the OnLoad event handler after the save has completed.  I also want to force the page to refresh after the save is completed.

Google has shown me many web pages that reiterate the same information in the MSDN article, but they don't explain where to put the save method to add a callback after the form finishes saving.

I know that I can add Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true).then(callback) to a form control and have the page refresh that way, but I want the page to refresh after the save has completed.

How does one use Refresh() to refresh the form after the form is done saving?

Also, how do you use Save() to add a callback to the saving of the form that will run after the form is done saving?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling save and calling refresh in the save callback?

Save: [Xrm.Page.data (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx#BKMK_dataSave)

```
Xrm.Page.data.save(saveOptions).then(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Refresh: [Xrm.Page.data (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx#BKMK_refresh)

```
Xrm.Page.data.refresh(save).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Combined:

```
Xrm.Page.data.save().then(function(){Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false);});
```

-- EDIT --

I'm going to guess at what you're trying to do...

1. A change is made to the form
2. The user clicks save or an auto-save is executed
3. Once the CRM has fully saved the record, you want to perform some other javascript action?

One thing you could try is hooking into the form OnSave event. Use a javascript timeout to check the form's isDirty property. Once the form is not dirty anymore, the CRM has saved the data.

Create a new form library javascript file and add something like the following:
Create a new OnSave event for the form using 'SetExecuteOnSaveComplete' as the function to be called.

```
function ExecuteWhenSaveComplete(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(!Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty())
            return callback();
        //alert('not complete');
        ExecuteWhenSaveComplete(callback);
    }, 500);
}

function SetExecuteOnSaveComplete(){
    ExecuteWhenSaveComplete(function(){
        alert('form save complete');
        // do what you need to do
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately that did not work.  I was looking for a way to add a callback to the form's OnSave event handler.

Comment: I edited my answer - I think I understand what you need. As far as I can tell, there is no OnSaved event.

Comment: @DarrenHoehna did the edited version do what you needed? It looks like it would, or at least that it would work for the 3-step scenario he's outlined.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn I don't remember.  Sorry.  I haven't been at that job for over a year.

Comment: Ok, just trying to wrap up the loose ends for people coming along after. I think what's described there should work.

Comment: Just tested your method on D365 in 2021, works well!